# How to deal with the "undercover cop unearths den of crime" message?

Tags: simcity-4

In SimCity 4 Deluxe Edition, my city has 40k population and the only red labelled message comes from the public safety advisor. I built a local police station as the message says, but the message didn't disappear for years of the game-time.

When I click "*this locale*", the camera zooms in the red ellipse below. Since this area is already covered by the police station, I don't know what else to do.

[image: Screenshot:]

What should I do to get rid of the "*undercover cop unearths den of crime*" message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, click that cross (the one next to the message) to dismiss it. More than likely the problem is already dealt with, but the message hasn't gone away yet (if it returns then you do have a problem - if not, all good).

If you do have a problem, all you can do is increase the police presence / make crime unnatractive. That means you can:

- Increase funding of existing police stations (Bigger Police Presence)
- Create more Police Stations (Bigger Police Presence)
- Remove Gambling Laws (Lowers Crime Attractiveness)
- Have an Educated Populace (Lowers Crime Attractiveness)

  - Invest in Universities, Libraries and School
  - Make it so the rich demographic dominates your city
- Adapt your buildings to counter the type of crime

  - eg: If there are a lot of shoplifters, rezone commercial areas as residential/industrial
- Create Roads so the Police can actually get to the buildings being targetted

Comment: Dismissing the message didn't solve the problem, it appears again after a while. I'll try your other suggestions as well.

Comment: @ahmedus Just took a closer look at your image and realized something that I forgot to mention before. I've edited the answer. I forgot to mention **roads**. You can have as many police stations as you want, but you have to have road access to the buildings you want having police protection. This is also valid for the Fire Department (when there's a fire). If you want to test your road access, click the emergency button at the left side and try sending a cop car to a building that may not have pathing

Comment: I built roads. After a while the message appeared again, but then disappeared itself. At least 5 years passed so far without the message. In addition, I built a deluxe police station in the residential area and dispatched the police helicopter to the problematic area. I don't know if it has a positive impact, but one of your suggestions certainly solves the problem. Thanks very much, I accept your answer.

Comment: @ahmedus One thing that could make your criminals show up (and being hard to deal with) is having that shithole section of a town, pretty much everything you got there (factories, landfill and a max-security prison) make the residents hate it -> thus crime

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of it. I kept these buildings away from the residental area, but I intend to destroy them once the budget gets a better shape.

Comment: The problem here is the airport: there is a bug in the game whereby crime around an airport cannot be completely eliminated, there will always be a segment of the grid it occupies that has relatively high crime - even if you put 10 deluxe stations all around it. There are plugins available on Simtropolis and the STEX toe correct this

Answer (score 1):

I have found out it's a game bug due to the large tile objects. The police can't penetrate beyond three tiles. So the solution for the airport is to surround it with roads (do this for all large tiles such as the golf course, university, etc), place a deluxe police station at both long ends around the middle, and a police kiosk at every corner. Also as others said make sure your sims are educated and after awhile you won't have either crimes or fires. If crime persists at the airport and messages drive you crazy, anyway, blow up the airport and let the game run a month, then put it back. Goes for all large tiles that keep having crime messages regardless of police stations nearby. It means the game has randomly put a crime in a center tile where police can't get to so it remains unsolved.